# Is there any free library to covert doc to pdf without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in c# environment

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I meet a problem about how to using c# without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to covert doc to pdf. I have tried some third party solution, like spire.Doc, but they are not free, and also I found DocX_Doc in nuget, but it seems there is no tutorial about that.Is anyone knows a free solution for this problem, or any instruction about DocX_Doc. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question as I see it is asking for a library (which is out of SO's scope). Also I had some experience with pdf in C# and I believe that there is no decent free library to do it (ofc "decency" depends on what is actually inside the document).

Answer (score 7):

you can use libreOffice is free license under apache 2.0 https://www.libreoffice.org/
i already tested it and it's working perefectly just you need to download soffice.exe file to convert to pdf you also can convert docx to image and other type.

here my example code that i tested it:

```
    static string getLibreOfficePath()
    {
        switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
        {
            case PlatformID.Unix:
                return "/usr/bin/soffice";
            case PlatformID.Win32NT:
                string binaryDirectory = 
          System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                return @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe";
            default:
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Your OS is not supported");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string libreOfficePath = getLibreOfficePath();

        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(libreOfficePath, 
        string.Format("--convert-to pdf C:\\test.docx")); //test.docx => input path
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = procStartInfo, };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        // Check for failed exit code.
        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            throw new LibreOfficeFailedException(process.ExitCode);
        }
    }
```

i hope it's helpfull for you.
Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Update:
as mentioned above by @saleem you need to use  https://www.libreoffice.org/

The following solution is obsolete as those libraries are not free anymore:

- For DocX library [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) and here is a sample on how to convert from word to PDF [Converting .docx into (.doc, .pdf, .html)](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com.tr/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html) **"Free"**
- You can check this DLL as well [enter link description here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/698727/convert-word-file-to-pdf-using-C-Sharp/)
- I use SautinSoft.UseOffice to do this, it's simple and easy to use but costs about 350$. Here is the link to a full tutorial:

[Convert DOC (DOCX) file to PDF file in C# - Step by Step](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Convert-DOC-DOCX-file-to-5c32bc0a) **"Not Free"**

Comment: The link you cite uses Interop: http://cathalscorner.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html

Comment: DocX cannot convert to PDF it seems, only a paid version supports creating PDF files...

Comment: DocX is not free for PDF conversion by the looks of it

Comment: @AltF4 at the time it was free :)

Comment: Shame I missed out on that, do you know of any alternatives that would now be free?